# ¿Como extraer los datos de un JSONOBject en java?

Tags: java, json, jsonobject

Tengo un campo String llamado **ejemplo** que contiene lo siguiente:

```html
{"listPruebas": [

 

    {

      "nombrePrueba" : "pruebaA",

 

      "id" : 1,

 

      "tipoPrueba" : "PRUEBABASE1",

 

      "elementoBase" : "tipoA",

 

            "listaMarca": [

 

            {

 

                "elemento": "elemento1 ",

 

                "tipo": "ABC",

 

                "cadena": "SFSG34235WF32"

 

            },

 

            {

 

                 "elemento":"elemento2",

 

                 "tipo":"DEF",

 

                 "cadena":"DJRT64353GSDG"

 

            },

 

            {

 

                "elemento" : "elemento3",

 
                "tipo":"HIJ"

                 "cadena":"DJRT64353GSDG"

 

            }

 

    ]},

 

    {

 

      "nombrePrueba" : "pruebaB",

 

      "id" : 2,

 

      "tipoPrueba" : "PRUEBABASE2",

 

      "elementoBase" : "imagenPrueba",

 

            "listaMarca": [

 

               {

 

                   "elemento" : "imagen",

 

                   "tipo": "tipo5",

 

                   "cadena": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAA"

 

                }

 

            ]

    }

 

 

 

            ],

 

 

 

                "listaBuscar":

 

                [

 

                {

 

                               "tipoBusqueda":"busqueda1",

 

                               "id" : 1,

 

                               "operacion" : "operacion1",

 

                               "valor" : "12"

 

                },

 

                {

 

                               "tipoBusqueda":"binario",

 

                               "id" : 2,

 

                               "operacion" : "operacion2",

 

                               "valor" : "13"

 

                },

 

                {

 

                               "tipoFiltro":"numerico",

 

                               "id" : 31,

 

                               "operacion" : "MENOR_QUE",

 

                               "valor" : "1980",

 

                               "intervalo" : 1

 

                }

 

                ]

 

 

 

 

}
```

y lo transforme a JSONObject de la siguiente manera

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(ejemplo);
```

y obtuve lo siguiente

```html
jsonObject::{"listaBuscar":[{"valor":"12","id":1,"operacion":"operacion1","tipoBusqueda":"busqueda1"},{"valor":"13","id":2,"operacion":"operacion2","tipoBusqueda":"binario"},{"tipoFiltro":"numerico","intervalo":1,"valor":"1980","id":31,"operacion":"MENOR_QUE"}],"listPruebas":[{"listaMarca":[{"tipo":"ABC","elemento":"elemento1","cadena":"SFSG34235WF32"},{"tipo":"DEF","elemento":"elemento2","cadena":"DJRT64353GSDG"},{"elemento":"elemento3","formato":"JPG"}],"elementoBase":"tipoA","tipoPrueba":"PRUEBABASE1","nombrePrueba":"pruebaA","id":1},{"elementoBase":"imagenPrueba","tipoPrueba":"PRUEBABASE2","listaMarca2":[{"tipo":"tipo5","elemento":"imagen","cadena":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAA"}],"nombrePrueba":"pruebaB","id":2}]}
```

Como puedo extraer la informacion de ese object? necesito con esa informacion ir llenando objetos, pero no se como extraerlos

Comment: Si tienes cosas que añadir sobre tu uso de la solución, edita la pregunta. No vandalices la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar páginas para formatear tu json y tengas una lectura más fácil de la estructura que tiene y con eso saber cómo sacarlo poco a poco, por si es un array [] o si es un objeto {}

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Intenta con esto:

```
String ejemplo = "{'listaBuscar':[{'valor':'12','id':1,'operacion':'operacion1','tipoBusqueda':'busqueda1'},{'valor':'13','id':2,'operacion':'operacion2','tipoBusqueda':'binario'},{'tipoFiltro':'numerico','intervalo':1,'valor':'1980','id':31,'operacion':'MENOR_QUE'}],'listPruebas':[{'listaMarca':[{'tipo':'ABC','elemento':'elemento1','cadena':'SFSG34235WF32'},{'tipo':'DEF','elemento':'elemento2','cadena':'DJRT64353GSDG'},{'elemento':'elemento3','formato':'JPG'}],'elementoBase':'tipoA','tipoPrueba':'PRUEBABASE1','nombrePrueba':'pruebaA','id':1},{'elementoBase':'imagenPrueba','tipoPrueba':'PRUEBABASE2','listaMarca2':[{'tipo':'tipo5','elemento':'imagen','cadena':'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAA'}],'nombrePrueba':'pruebaB','id':2}]}";

    //Lo paso primero a Objeto porque empieza con {}
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(ejemplo);
    //Luego saco el primer Array porque es listaBuscar y empieza con []
    JSONArray arrayObject = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("listaBuscar");

    // Después lo recorres
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayObject.length(); i++) {
        // Este if es para cuando llegue al tercer objeto que tiene diferentes atributos a los demás.
        if (i == 2) {
            JSONObject object2 = (JSONObject) arrayObject.get(i);

            String tipoFiltro = object2.get("tipoFiltro").toString();
            String intervalo = object2.get("intervalo").toString();
            String valor2 = object2.get("valor").toString();
            String id2 = object2.get("id").toString();
            String operacion2 = object2.get("operacion").toString();

            System.out.println("tipoFiltro:" + tipoFiltro);
            System.out.println("intervalo:" + intervalo);
            System.out.println("operacion:" + operacion2);
            System.out.println("valor:" + valor2);
            System.out.println("id:" + id2);
            System.out.println("operacion:" + operacion2);
        }
        //Aquí se imprimen los 2 primeros objetos porque tienen los mismos atributos
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) arrayObject.get(i);
        String valor = object.get("valor").toString();
        String id = object.get("id").toString();
        String operacion = object.get("operacion").toString();
        String tipoBusqueda = object.get("id").toString();

        System.out.println("valor:" + valor);
        System.out.println("id:" + id);
        System.out.println("operacion:" + operacion);
        System.out.println("tipoBusqueda:" + tipoBusqueda);

    }
```

Y ya solo haces los mismo con el segundo array e ir sacando los objetos o array que están dentro, esto solo es un ejemplo para sacar los objetos del primer array "listaBuscar":[].

Tu primer arreglo tiene 3 objetos, los 2 primeros están en la posición 0 y 1 y esos 2 primeros tienen los mismos atributos que son:

```
"valor"
"id"
"operacion"
"tipoBusqueda"
```

Y esos 2 primeros objetos se pintan con lo que está fuera del if.
el tercer objeto tiene atributos diferentes al de los 2 primeros el tercer objeto tiene estos atributos:

```
"tipoFiltro"
"intervalo"
"valor"
"id"
"operacion"
```

Entonces cuando el for haga el tercer recorrido, va a estar en la posición 2 del array, recuerda que los array empiezan de 0, cuando llegue a la posición 2 estará en el objeto 3 y este al tener atributos diferentes saco los atributos de ese objeto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias, lo he probado y todo OK, solo que no entendí la parte del if = 2, o sea que si quiero pintar lo demás elementos que contiene la lista tengo meter lo mismo pero con otros if = 1 o 0? gracias

Comment: tampoco entendi muy bien para que se vuelve a repetir los string en parte de abajo fuera del for?

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses el debug en tu IDE y pon un breackpoint en en el inicio del ciclo for, y ahí podrás ver como funciona línea a línea el código y los valores de cada variable.

Comment: ya me quedo mas claro, mil gracias. Agregue también lo que seria para acceder a las otras listas, pero me quedo una duda en esa parte, edite  tu respuesta con lo que tengo. gracias